# ASP.NET Core OkObjectResult with XmlDocument is ignoring accept header

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm seeing some ASP.NET core behavior that I simply do not understand. To repro:

Make a new app using the API template (right now its using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.8`).

Modify the values controller as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var xmlContent = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xmlContent.LoadXml("<MyData><StringProperty>foo</StringProperty></MyData>");
        return new OkObjectResult(xmlContent);
    }
```

Run the app and hit that API with an accept:application/xml e.g.

```
GET http://localhost:3287/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3287
Accept: application/xml
```

You'll get the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 22:55:00 GMT
Content-Length: 35

{"MyData":{"StringProperty":"foo"}}
```

The client requested XML from the server, the server had an XML result, and yet returned JSON.

I'm aware of various workarounds (such as using ContentResult) but I'd like to understand if this is expected behavior and if so, why?

Comment: Have you tried setting the return type to `XmlDocument` instead of `IActionResult` and then return `xmlContent`?

Comment: Yeah there are various ways to make this scenario work but what I want to know is why it does not work as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Booth pointed me the answer - XmlSerializerFormatters need to be added like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
    }
```

After doing this, I get the expected behavior:

```
GET http://localhost:3287/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3287
Accept: application/xml

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 29 May 2018 19:45:48 GMT
Content-Length: 53

<MyData><StringProperty>foo</StringProperty></MyData>
```